# I want to restart countdown twice a day at my desired time

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I made a javascript countdown, it works well. But I want it to restart twice a day as I ship my orders twice a day. 
1- 11AM PST
2- 4PM PST

I want it to show countdown time for 11AM PST after 4PM PST of clock time and after 11AM it should reset and show countdown for 4PM and after 4PM PST it should reset and show countdown for 11PM PST

Here is my countdown code.

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("July 26, 2019 11:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Instead of "EXPIRED" action reset your `countDownDate`.

Comment: That is the confusion, I am confused how to restart it and end at 11 AM and then end at 4PM and then 11AM

Comment: Can you please modify the code for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, there are 2 or 3 obscure points in your request, as for example the passage of 11 to 16 erases the value 'EXPIRED' of the display. There is also the question of whether this script runs continuously or if it is restarted each morning (this is the option I chose) if it runs continuously it assumes that the countdown is restarted from 16h on that of 11h the next morning?

Here is the first proposal :

```js
const CountDown = [ { elm: document.querySelector('#c11 span'), target:[11,00,00], time:0 }
                  , { elm: document.querySelector('#c16 span'), target:[16,00,00], time:0 }
                  ]
  ,   one_Sec   = 1000
  ,   one_Min   = one_Sec * 60
  ,   one_Hour  = one_Min * 60 


let JustNow       = new Date() 
  , idx_CountDown = -1
  , refTimeLeft   = 0

CountDown.forEach( (Cd, idx)=>
  {
    Cd.time = new Date()

    Cd.time.setHours( Cd.target[0] )
    Cd.time.setMinutes( Cd.target[1] )
    Cd.time.setSeconds( Cd.target[2] )

    let TimeLeft = JustNow - Cd.time

    Cd.elm.textContent = (TimeLeft<0) ? 'not yet' : 'EXPIRED'

    if ( TimeLeft < 0 && (TimeLeft > refTimeLeft || refTimeLeft === 0 ))
    {
      idx_CountDown = idx
      refTimeLeft   = TimeLeft
    }
  })

if (refTimeLeft < 0)
  {
  let timerInterval = setInterval(_=>
    {
    let JustNow  = new Date()
      , TimeLeft = JustNow - CountDown[idx_CountDown].time
      , TimeLPlus = Math.abs( TimeLeft )
      ,  Hrs     = ('0' + Math.floor(TimeLPlus / one_Hour)).slice(-2)
      ,  Mns     = ('0' + Math.floor((TimeLPlus % one_Hour) / one_Min)).slice(-2)
      ,  Scs     = ('0' + Math.floor((TimeLPlus % one_Min) / one_Sec)).slice(-2)

    if (TimeLeft>=0) 
      {
      CountDown[idx_CountDown].elm.textContent = 'EXPIRED'
      if (++idx_CountDown>=CountDown.length)
        { clearInterval(timerInterval) }
      }
    else
      {
      CountDown[idx_CountDown].elm.textContent = `${Hrs}h ${Mns}m ${Scs}s`
      }  
    }
    , one_Sec)
  }
```

```html
<h4>CountDowns</h4>

<p id="c11">until 11h : <span></span> </p>
<p id="c16">until 16h : <span></span> </p>
```

**version 2** *perpetual with only 1 countdown*

```js
const lib_Count = document.querySelector('#count-element span:nth-child(1)')
  ,   val_Count = document.querySelector('#count-element span:nth-child(2)')
  ,   CountDown = [ { target:[11,00,00], time:0, lib : 'until 11h : ' }
                  , { target:[16,00,00], time:0, lib : 'until 16h : ' }
  /* Add any time you need ---> , { target:[20,00,00], time:0, lib : 'until 20h : ' }  ---- */
                  ]
  ,   one_Sec   = 1000
  ,   one_Min   = one_Sec * 60
  ,   one_Hour  = one_Min * 60 

let JustNow       = new Date() 
  , idx_CountDown = -1
  , refTimeLeft   = 0

// prepare CountDowns for the day
CountDown.forEach( (Cd, idx)=>
  {
    Cd.time = new Date()
    Cd.time.setHours( Cd.target[0] )
    Cd.time.setMinutes( Cd.target[1] )
    Cd.time.setSeconds( Cd.target[2] )

    let TimeLeft = JustNow - Cd.time

    if (TimeLeft>=0) 
      {
      Cd.time.setDate(Cd.time.getDate() + 1)
      TimeLeft = JustNow - Cd.time
      }

    if (TimeLeft > refTimeLeft || refTimeLeft === 0 )
      {
      idx_CountDown         = idx
      refTimeLeft           = TimeLeft
      lib_Count.textContent = Cd.lib
      val_Count.textContent = ''
      }
  })

setInterval(_=>
  {
  let JustNow  = new Date()
    , TimeLeft = JustNow - CountDown[idx_CountDown].time
    , TimeLPlus = Math.abs( TimeLeft )
    ,  Hrs     = ('0' + Math.floor(TimeLPlus / one_Hour)).slice(-2)
    ,  Mns     = ('0' + Math.floor((TimeLPlus % one_Hour) / one_Min)).slice(-2)
    ,  Scs     = ('0' + Math.floor((TimeLPlus % one_Min) / one_Sec)).slice(-2)

  if (TimeLeft>=0) 
    {
    CountDown[idx_CountDown].time.setDate(CountDown[idx_CountDown].time.getDate() + 1)

    idx_CountDown = (idx_CountDown +1) % CountDown.length
    lib_Count.textContent = CountDown[idx_CountDown].lib
    val_Count.textContent = ''
    }
  else
    {
    val_Count.textContent = `${Hrs}h ${Mns}m ${Scs}s`
    }  
  }
  , one_Sec )
```

```html
<h4>CountDown</h4>

<p id="count-element"><span></span><span></span> </p>
```

Comment: This is better. But I want to show only one countdown it shows 2 and when 1 stop 2nd starts, I want only 1 and reset it at the required time

Comment: Yes, I don't need to see the expired, I only need to see one count down and when it expire it should replace with second.

Comment: Also it should automatically start 1st countdown time 11AM PST when second expired. currently I tested it and it doesn't start 1st when second expired

Comment: Thank you very much @Mister Jojo

Comment: One last thing please, if I want to display 3 different shipping times, what I would need to add in this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following logic,

- here there are two functions
- first function will contain your logic for doing the countdown
- second function will add 11 hours to current date and then call the first function
- When first function (11 hrs countdown) is finished, it will again call the second function and so on

---

```
// set the current date and time
var currentCountDown = // current date

// call nextCountDown and pass current date which will set the countdown for 
// next 11 hours
nextCountDown(currentCountDown)

function doCountDown(countDownDate) {
    // put the above code in this function
    // If the count down is over, call nextCountDown to start the countdown 
    // for next interval 
    nextCountDown(countDownDate)
}

function nextCountDown(countDownDate){
    // add 11 hours to countDownDate
    newCountDownDate = countDownDate + 11 hours
    // call doCountDown() by passing the new date
    doCountDown(newCountDownDate)
}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted it into my code but it stopped the code to work. Can you please copy my code and modify it and put it here please?

Comment: @UIXpider Rahul Vala has shown you a method you can use. Have a go at using his logic to make it work in your own code.

Comment: @sorifiend I'm really sorry but not getting where I have to place and which needs to remove from my code to make it work. Can you please put it in my code and paste the code here which works actually?