# how to make a pomodoro timer countdown in minutes and secods with a onclick btn

Tags: javascript, clock

Im having the worst time trying to figure this out, I'm making this pomodoro clock using basic javascript, i already made the session and break lengths work but i don't get how to make it work with the session and then to go to the break lengths, if you be so kind to explain it to me please, i really want to learn to code.

```
function incrementBreak() {
   let breakLength = document.getElementById("break-length");
   if (parseFloat(breakLength.innerText) < 60) {
       breakLength.innerText = parseFloat(breakLength.innerText) + 1;

   }
   
}
function decrementBreak() {
   let breakLength = document.getElementById("break-length");
   if (parseFloat(breakLength.innerText) > 0) {
       breakLength.innerText = parseFloat(breakLength.innerText) - 1;

   }

}
function incrementSession(){
   let sessionLength = document.getElementById("session-length");
   if (parseFloat(sessionLength.innerText) < 60) {
       let incrementedSessionValue = parseFloat(sessionLength.innerText) + 1;
       sessionLength.innerText = incrementedSessionValue;
       document.getElementById("minutes").innerText = incrementedSessionValue;
   }
}
function decrementSession() {
   let sessionLength = document.getElementById("session-length");
   if (parseFloat(sessionLength.innerText) > 0) {
       let decrementedSessionValue = parseFloat(sessionLength.innerText) - 1;
       sessionLength.innerText = decrementedSessionValue;
       document.getElementById("minutes").innerText = decrementedSessionValue;
   }
}
var secondsLeft = 60;
var minutesLeft = document.getElementById("minutes");
function toggleOnOff(){ `this is the onclick`
       var Timer = setInterval(function 
           function1(){ 
       document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = secondsLeft;
       
       secondsLeft -= 1;
       if(secondsLeft <= 0){
           clearInterval(Timer);
           var Timer2 = setInterval(function
               function2() {
               document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minutesLeft;

               minutesLeft -= 1;
               if (minutesLeft <= 0){
                   clearInterval(Timer2);
               }
               },1000)
       }
       }, 1000);
       
           console.log(countdown);
       

}
```

Comment: Hey, nice job so far. Don’t get discouraged. So I can start helping you, can you verify if you are trying to take custom intervals from the user? Or, are you trying to do the standard pomodoro? I think the standard is [25, 5, 25, 5, 25, 60], but I could be wrong.

Comment: you must not use the delay argument of the setInterval, it is a false measure of time, you must use the local time (new Date ()) to establish the elapsed time (in your setInterval)

Comment: yes is a 25 + 5 clock that goes to 60 minutes with 5 min breaks, so how do i implement the (new Date()), should i put it inside the setinterval?

Comment: yes like any countdown here  some of mine : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57210944/i-want-to-restart-countdown-twice-a-day-at-my-desired-time/57211872#57211872   or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58294674/modify-countdown-script-to-allow-for-multiple-countdowns-per-page/58477464#58477464

Comment: cool but i broked it lol

Comment: now it wont do anything